# Where does System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write output appear?

Tags: c#, debugging

The following C# program (built with `csc hello.cs`) prints just `Hello via Console!` on the console and `Hello via OutputDebugString` in the DebugView window. However, I cannot see either of the `System.Diagnostics.*` calls. Why is that?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Hello {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern void OutputDebugString(string message);

    static void Main() {
        Console.Write( "Hello via Console!" );
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write( "Hello via Debug!" );
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write( "Hello via Trace!" );
        OutputDebugString( "Hello via OutputDebugString" );
    }
}
```

Is there maybe some special command-line switches required for `csc`?

I'm not using Visual Studio for any of my development, this is pure commandline stuff.

Comment: as mentioned at some comment in another reply, can use Microsoft's (SysInternals) DebugView: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As others have pointed out, listeners have to be registered in order to read these streams. Also note that `Debug.Write` will only function if the `DEBUG` build flag is set, while `Trace.Write` will only function if the `TRACE` build flag is set.

Setting the `DEBUG` and/or `TRACE` flags is easily done in the project properties in Visual Studio or by supplying the following arguments to csc.exe

> `/define:DEBUG;TRACE`

Comment: It was useful (didn't expect that) for me to find out that Debug and Trace objects use the same trace listeners, therefore, both Debug.Write and Trace.Write output to the same place(s), it is just that depending on conditions they might not get executed

Comment: could you elaborate on what *conditions* they are? exactly which situation  a debug.Write will not work the same as a trace.write?

Comment: this doesnt work for me, i have debug and trace flags set in vs project properties, and am using Debug.WriteLine, the line executes, but nothing appears in the output window, anyone got any other advise?

Comment: To expand on @hello_earth comment, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.write?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 131):

While debugging `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` will display in the output window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>), you can also add a `TraceListener` to the `Debug.Listeners` collection to specify `Debug.WriteLine` calls to output in other locations.

Note: `Debug.WriteLine` calls may not display in the output window if you have the Visual Studio option "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" checked under the menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Debugging* → *General*. To display "*Tools* → *Options* → *Debugging*", check the box next to "*Tools* → *Options* → *Show All Settings*".

Comment: I would like to confirm that (Ctrl + Alt + O) will bring up the output window while debugging in Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 52):

You need to add a `TraceListener` to see them appear on the Console.

```
TextWriterTraceListener writer = new TextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out);
Debug.Listeners.Add(writer);
```

They also appear in the Visual Studio Output window when in Debug mode.

Comment: Apparently DebugView will capture both the .NET Debug.Write() and Win32 OutputDebugString(): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647

Comment: @dlchambers: I don't think that's correct. That page claims display of `OutputDebugString()` and (kernel) `DbgPrint().`

Comment: @dlchambers: I withdraw the comment; I discovered that DebugView can capture `Debug.Write()` *if* its Capture settings include "Global Win32" -- which requires running it in Admin mode.

Answer (score 13):

While you are debugging in Visual Studio, display the "Output" window (View->Output). It will show there.

Answer (score 7):

The Diagnostics messages are displayed in the Output Window.

Answer (score 5):

When I write `Debug.Write("")` in the code, it outputs in the "Immediate window", not "Output window".

You can try it. For displaying the "Immediate" window (*Debug* → *Window* → *Immediate*).

Answer (score 2):

The solution for my case is:

1. Right click the output window;
2. Check the 'Program Output'

Answer (score 1):

For VB.NET the following applies. You have to select "Debug" AND make sure that you "Start Debugging". This can be reached by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Also the Console.WriteLine will only display messages when building as "Release" in your Output window.

As mentioned before, open the Output window with *View* → *Output* AND make sure to select either "Build" if you want to see Console.WriteLine messages or "Debug" if you want to see Debug.WriteLine or Trace.WriteLine messages.