# Writing messages with Debug.Write in VS2012?

Tags: c#

I am using the following in my C# code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("xxx");
```

But when I look in the output window I cannot see anything even though my code does execute this line.

Is this the correct way to write messages that I can see in the VS2012?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159755/where-does-system-diagnostics-debug-write-output-appear

Comment: Is the writing of messages immediate or does it have to be flushed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Debug.Write` will only function if the `DEBUG` build flag is set.

OR

- `Debug.Write` calls may not display in the output window if you have the Visual Studio option "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" checked under the menu

> Tools > Options > Debugging > General.

To display `"Tools > Options > Debugging"`, check the box next to "Tools > Options > Show All Settings".

[image: Debugging]

Comment: Hi, Vishal. I don't have that button checked.

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG` build flag set.?

Comment: So that's may be the cause, so please change it to `Debug` and check.