# how to check the value present in a datatable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datatable

I have populated the value for a datatable by using the value in a database. The data willl get populated into database on a button click. Can anybody tell how to check the value in the datatable which is populated. 
I am using visual studio and coding in c#

The code for populating the datatable is as shown below :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            var sql = @"select scriptname,accnum,Quantity,price from transac where transactio = 'Sell'";
            var dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            var dataTablesell = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTablesell);


        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            Response.Write("error" + sqlEx.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTable` has a very nice `DebuggerVisualizer`. Set a breakpoint after `dataAdapter.Fill(dataTablesell);` line; when the breakpoint is hit, hover cursor over `dataTablesell` to open a debug view and click magnifier button (`O-`) to open visualizer

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through rows of `DataTable` to get the value in each row for given columns.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dataTablesell.Rows)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(row["scriptname"].ToString()); //use cell value where you want
    Debug.WriteLine(row["accnum"].ToString()); //use cell value where you want
}
```

You can also bind the `DataTable` to `DataGridView` to see the rows in the DataTable. This MSDN article [How to: Bind Data to the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.90).aspx) explains how you would do that.

Comment: where the line will be printed.. I have not redirected the page after button click... can I see the value in the same page after button click??

Comment: You can use Visual Studio output window, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159755/where-does-system-diagnostics-debug-write-output-appear

Answer (score 1):

got the answer...
Instead of using Console.WriteLine as Adil has said, I used Response.Write, The code is

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTablesell.Rows)
            {
                Response.Write(row["scriptname"].ToString()); 
                Response.Write(row["accnum"].ToString()); 
            }
```