# C#, Visual Studio 2013: Debug.WriteLine doesn't output to Output Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've read through other similar questions but nothing has worked for me.  I've changed debugging settings to check this against the most common answers.

Project Type is a class library.

Why does this code not print anything in the output window?

```
public class API 
    {
        public void  BrowseDirectory() {
            string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(allFiles);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the Immediate Window? Check that you don't have the "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" option checked in VS options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write output appear?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159755/where-does-system-diagnostics-debug-write-output-appear)

Comment: Do you have this option disabled? `Go to Tools – Options – Debugging – General page.  Under this page, you’ll find the option Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window.` Try switching it.

Comment: I don't see anything in the Immediate Window, and I have that option unchecked.  Also DEBUG and TRACE flags are both set in project properties.

Comment: At the top of the "Output" window there's a drop-list entitled "Show output from:". Does it say "Debug"? If not, see if you can select it from the drop-list. Also, is the DLL build by a different project? If so, are you sure you've rebuilt it (and not just the project you are debugging from)?

Comment: Output is set to Debug.  DLL isn't built by another project.  This is all there is.

Comment: Already read through the other question Alfie linked, and I have all settings set to the recommendations in that thread.  Still no luck.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? It will only print `System.String[]`. What happens if you use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", allFiles));`?

Comment: expecting to see print out of each file in the directory.  Still don't see anything with your line.

Comment: It doesn't print anything because the statement does not execute.  Remove try/catch from your code so you can see the Directory.GetFiles() method fail with an UnauthorizedAccessException.  Don't put them back until you know how to actually handle the exception.

Comment: there is no 'try/catch' in the code.

Comment: Something beyond what we can see is wrong. Can you debug into the line of code in question? Can you set a breakpoint on it?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out.  I set a breakpoint but am not seeing anything during debugging.  I'm pretty new to C# and .NET.  I'm going to have to do some more digging.