# Console writeline does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, console.writeline

I'm debugging a UWP in C#. On a certain moment the console stops giving me the write line content.

Does anyone can imagen what the problem could be?

[image]

Comment: The output window isn't the *console*

Comment: You mean `Debug.WriteLine`

Comment: use Debug.WriteLine instead

Comment: Console.WriteLine or Debug.Writeline are inappropriate for tracing or logging. Use a proper logging library

Comment: BTW Debug.WriteLine won't work in Release builds.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` works fine, but for some project it does not. With `WPF + .Net Framework` it works, with `WPF + .Net Core 3` it does not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Console.WriteLine` isn't for IDE output window. It writes to console. So, you could use `Debug.WriteLine()` which is available in `System.Diagnostics`

Comment: Only for debug builds though

Comment: Also remember that you need DEBUG flag to use this. see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159755/where-does-system-diagnostics-debug-write-output-appear)

Comment: Oh man, I totally forgot which one to use.  Why doesn't Console.WriteLine throw an error when there's no console?

Answer (score 4):

`Console.WriteLine` or `Debug.Writeline` are inappropriate for tracing or logging. The real solution is to use a logging library.

The Output Window of the debugger is *not* the console. If you want to write to it use `Debug.WriteLine`. You can do this because the Output Window is registered as a listener for .NET's tracing infrastructure.

This won't work in Release mode though. You'd need to use `Trace.WriteLine` for this *but* you'd also need to register your own listeners. You'd also need to specify message levels to separate errors from verbose messages and eg write only erros to log files.

At this point though, it's just as easy to add and configure a logging library like Serilog or NLog that have providers for rolling files, databases, logging servers etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna see some messages in "Output" you should use `Debug.WriteLine`. For this add `using System.Diagnostics`.

If you use WindowsForm, for example, you can't just use `Console.WriteLine`.