# How is Visual Studio or Rider reading messages written using System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write?

Tags: c#, logging, visual-studio-debugging

My understanding is that you need to [register a listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159755/where-does-system-diagnostics-debug-write-output-appear) to the trace output, but how would that even look like? Is there a trace stream associated with each execution of the application that Visual Studio/Rider listens to?

We can rephrase this question by asking:
How to write a simple console app that executes another application and listen to its trace output.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/TraceInternal.cs,e19765f8de74589d Like the source code indicates, the information would be written to listeners, and https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Trace.cs,30 shows where you should register yours. Visual Studio/Rider uses a debugger to hook to the applications they launch, so that they can manipulate things. I won't call that's "simple". But if you have enough permissions on the machine, you can modify `app.config` of that application to insert your listener.

Comment: @LexLi: No hooking, sending trace messages to a debugger is a standard OS API (`OutputDebugString`) that the .NET Debug and Trace classes use (with their default listener).

Comment: @BenVoigt Great to know that. Then it would be much easier to collect the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive another application's debugging output, you need to attach to it as a debugger and call [the `WaitForDebugEvent` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681423(v=VS.85).aspx), looking for [`OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680545(v=vs.85).aspx) results (`dwDebugEventCode == OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT`)

If the other application is .NET, you potentially have some easier options, including configuring additional trace listeners in the `app.config`.

Comment: I guess the next thing for me to find out is how a debugger attaches and communicates with an application.